# JQuery: change default binding of element

Tags: jquery, binding

How can I change the click binding of an element?
Html snippet is:

```
<div id="Selected">
<ul>
    <li>element 01<a class="element01-selected">-</a></li>
    <li>element 02<a class="element02-selected">-</a></li>
    <li>element 03<a class="element03-selected">-</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="UnSelected">
<ul>
    <li>element 01<a class="element01-unselected">+</a></li>
    <li>element 02<a class="element02-unselected">+</a></li>
    <li>element 03<a class="element03-unselected">+</a></li>
    <li>element 04<a class="element04-unselected">+</a></li>
    <li>element 05<a class="element05-unselected">+</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

At the moment, I initialize the bindings like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$("#Selected ul li a").click(
    function()
    {
        // do stuffs
        return false;
    }
);
$("#UnSelected ul li a").click(
    function ()
    {
    var li = $(this).parent();
    $clone = li.clone(false);
    $clone.children().text("-");
    $("#Selected ul").append($clone);
    return false;
    }
);
</script>
```

The element is copied to the 1st list but the click bind remains, I want the item clicked to switch to the other binding:

- + link adds a copy (where + is changed to -) into the 1st list
- - link of added copy removes the item from the 1st list

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using delegate to attach the events. This way if you add any new element to this it will trigger the fire the same events.

```
$("#Selected").delegate("ul li a", "click", function()
    {
        // do stuffs
        return false;
    }
);
$("#UnSelected").delegate("ul li a", "click", function ()
    {
    var li = $(this).parent();
    $clone = li.clone(false);
    $clone.children().text("-");
    $("#Selected ul").append($clone);
    return false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unbind method to unbind any event attached to it.

e.g

```
$clone.unbind('click');
```

Comment: I got that part, but not the one to apply the new binding to the copied element, I can't get the copy to act as if it was loaded inside the 1st list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
[**unbind**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)  for this purpose

```
 $("#elementId").unbind('click');
```

in your code you can use this , something like this-

```
$("#UnSelected ul li a").click(   
function ()     {    
 $(this).unbind('click');
var li = $(this).parent();     
$clone = li.clone(false);     
$clone.children().text("-");    
 $("#Selected ul").append($clone);     
return false;     } );
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `unbind` only works if you have previously `bind`ed the click.

```
$("#Selected ul li a").bind('click',
    function( //do stuff )
);
$("#UnSelected ul li a").unbind('click',
    function ( //do stuff )
);
```